# highcharts: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm trying to feed some data from a REST API into HighCharts but I'm getting an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined`.

This gets the data from the API:

```
$scope.myData = function(chart) {

  HighCharts.query({
  }, 
  function(data) {
    $scope.highcharts = data;
    chart.series[0].setData($scope.getChart(data));
  });

};
```

Here's the `getChart` function:

```
$scope.getChart = function(data) {
    var response = [];

      $scope.highcharts.id.forEach(function(element, index){
        response.push([
          moment(element).toDate().getTime(),
          $scope.highcharts.value[index]
        ]);
      });

    return response;
  }
```

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong?

Update: I've updated the question as I'm getting a new error. You can see the full code at https://jsfiddle.net/raq0eg6e/.

Comment: means chart.series is undefined

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. Debug your code and check where something is `undefined`.

Comment: @epascarello How can I define it, then? - https://jsfiddle.net/raq0eg6e/

Comment: In `$scope.myData();` you should pass chart reference. If after fixing that problem, you are still having problems or errors - could you provide a fixed code? or even better - working, live example?

Answer (score 0):

This Line  throwing error

```
  chart.series[0]
```

Just define a variable as follow

```
var  chart =("#yourContainerId").highcharts();
```

Comment: Actually, I had forgot to call `chart` in the function. Here's my full code if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/raq0eg6e/ - it gives a new error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined`.

Comment: In your  $scope.init = function () {
      $scope.myData(); ............... you are missing the parameter myData(Give it a value for chart )

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it looks like `chart.series` is undefined. You can log its value before `chart.series[0].setData($scope.getChart(data));` with `console.log(chart.series)` to see if that is indeed the case.